# Transitions are not working properly in my slider game

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to code a slider puzzle game in react typescript.  Its a 3x3 grid of tiles. One tile in the grid is empty and when you click on a tile, it should "slide" that tile into the empty spot.  The game is complete when all the tiles are in the correct position.

I have a game component and then a board class and a tile class.

Here is the game file:

```
//Game.tsx
import { useState, useEffect, useRef, createRef, RefObject } from "react";
import "../assets/css/Game.css";

import { Button, Card, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

import Board from "./Board";

interface GameProps {
  imgSrc: string;
}

interface Offset {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

const BOARD_SIDE_LENGTH = 450; // CSS pixels
const TILE_SIDE_LENGTH = 150;

const Game: React.FC<GameProps> = ({ imgSrc }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState<HTMLImageElement | null>(null);
  const [offsets, setOffsets] = useState<Offset[]>([]);
  const [boardInstance, setBoardInstance] = useState<Board | null>(null);
  const [animationState, setAnimationState] = useState<{
    isAnimating: boolean;
    direction: string;
    tileId: number;
  }>({ isAnimating: false, direction: "", tileId: -1 });

  console.log("AnimationState: ", animationState);

  const tileRefs = useRef<(React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null)[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = imgSrc;
    img.onload = function () {
      const widthOriginal = img.width;
      const heightOriginal = img.height;

      const scalingFactor =
        BOARD_SIDE_LENGTH / Math.min(widthOriginal, heightOriginal);

      const widthResized = widthOriginal * scalingFactor;
      const heightResized = heightOriginal * scalingFactor;

      img.width = widthResized;
      img.height = heightResized;

      setImage(img);
    };

    const board = new Board();
    setBoardInstance(board);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
      setOffsets(splitImage(image));
    }
  }, [image]);

  useEffect(() => {
    tileRefs.current =
      (boardInstance?.tiles
        .flat()
        .map(() => createRef()) as React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>[]) || [];
  }, [boardInstance]);

  const handleMove = (tileId: number, rowIndex: number, colIndex: number) => {
    console.log("Handling Move ---------------------------");
    if (animationState.isAnimating) {
      return;
    }

    const direction = boardInstance?.getMoveDirection({ rowIndex, colIndex });
    console.log("Direction from getMoveDirection: ", direction);

    if (direction) {
      console.log("Direction Exists so continue...");
      setAnimationState({
        isAnimating: true,
        direction,
        tileId,
      });

      tileRefs.current[tileId]?.current?.addEventListener(
        "transitionend",
        () => {
          console.log("Animation ended...");
          setBoardInstance((prevBoard) => {
            if (prevBoard) {
              prevBoard.moveTile({ rowIndex, colIndex });
              console.log("Move successful");
              return prevBoard;
            }
            console.log("Board instance not initialized");
            return null;
          });
          setAnimationState({ isAnimating: false, direction: "", tileId: -1 });
          console.log("Board has been updated");
        },
        { once: true }
      );
    }

    console.log("End Handling Move -----------------------");
  };

  const splitImage = (image: HTMLImageElement): Offset[] => {
    const cx = (BOARD_SIDE_LENGTH - image.width) / 2;
    const cy = (BOARD_SIDE_LENGTH - image.height) / 2;

    const coordinates = [];

    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 3; rowIndex++) {
      for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < 3; colIndex++) {
        const x = cx - TILE_SIDE_LENGTH * colIndex;
        const y = cy - TILE_SIDE_LENGTH * rowIndex;

        coordinates.push({ x, y });
      }
    }

    return coordinates;
  };

  const renderTiles = () => {
    console.log("rendering Tiles...");
    return boardInstance?.tiles.map((row, rowIndex) =>
      row.map((tile, colIndex) => {
        if (!tile) {
          return <div key={"empty"}></div>;
        }

        const offset = offsets[tile.id];

        return (
          <div
            key={tile.id}
            ref={tileRefs.current[tile.id]}
            className={`tile${
              animationState.isAnimating && animationState.tileId === tile.id
                ? ` slide-${animationState.direction.toLowerCase()}`
                : ""
            }`}
            onClick={() => {
              handleMove(tile.id, rowIndex, colIndex);
            }}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: image ? `url(${image.src})` : "none",
              backgroundSize: image ? `${image.width}px ${image.height}px` : "",
              backgroundPosition: `${offset.x}px ${offset.y}px`,
            }}
          >
            {tile.id + 1}
          </div>
        );
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="slider-puzzle"
      >
        {offsets.length === 9 && renderTiles()}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Game;
```

Here is the board file:

```
//Board.ts
import Tile from "./Tile";
import { deepCopy } from "../utils/helper";

interface Position {
  rowIndex: number;
  colIndex: number;
}

class Board {
  tiles: (Tile | null)[][];

  constructor() {
    this.tiles = this.generateInitialBoard();
  }

  private generateInitialBoard(): (Tile | null)[][] {
    // Logic to generate the initial puzzle board
    const tiles: (Tile | null)[][] = [
      [new Tile(0), new Tile(1), new Tile(2)],
      [new Tile(3), new Tile(4), new Tile(5)],
      [new Tile(6), new Tile(7), null],
    ];

    // Return a 2D array of Tile objects
    return tiles;
  }

  private findEmptyPosition(): Position | null {
    let emptyPosition: Position | null = null;
    for (let r = 0; r < this.tiles.length; r++) {
      for (let c = 0; c < this.tiles[r].length; c++) {
        if (this.tiles[r][c] === null) {
          emptyPosition = { rowIndex: r, colIndex: c };
          break;
        }
      }
      if (emptyPosition) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return emptyPosition;
  }

  public getMoveDirection(position: Position): string | null {
    const neighbors = [
      {
        direction: "UP",
        rowIndex: position.rowIndex - 1,
        colIndex: position.colIndex,
      }, // Above
      {
        direction: "DOWN",
        rowIndex: position.rowIndex + 1,
        colIndex: position.colIndex,
      }, // Below
      {
        direction: "LEFT",
        rowIndex: position.rowIndex,
        colIndex: position.colIndex - 1,
      }, // Left
      {
        direction: "RIGHT",
        rowIndex: position.rowIndex,
        colIndex: position.colIndex + 1,
      }, // Right
    ];

    for (const neighbor of neighbors) {
      if (
        neighbor.rowIndex >= 0 &&
        neighbor.rowIndex < this.tiles.length &&
        neighbor.colIndex >= 0 &&
        neighbor.colIndex < this.tiles[neighbor.rowIndex].length
      ) {
        if (this.tiles[neighbor.rowIndex][neighbor.colIndex] === null) {
          return neighbor.direction;
        }
      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  /**
   * The `swap` function swaps two elements in the tiles 2D array.
   * @param {number} r1 - The rowIndex of the first tile to be swapped.
   * @param {number} c1 - The colIndex of the first tile to be swapped.
   * @param {number} r2 - The rowIndex of the second tile to be swapped.
   * @param {number} c2 - The colIndex of the second tile to be swapped.
   */
  private swap(r1: number, c1: number, r2: number, c2: number): void {
    const temp = this.tiles[r1][c1];
    this.tiles[r1][c1] = this.tiles[r2][c2];
    this.tiles[r2][c2] = temp;
  }

  public moveTile(position: Position): void {
    const emptyPosition = this.findEmptyPosition();
    const moveDirection = this.getMoveDirection(position);

    // console.log("emptyPosition: ", emptyPosition);
    // console.log("moveDirection: ", moveDirection);

    if (moveDirection && emptyPosition) {
      this.swap(
        position.rowIndex,
        position.colIndex,
        emptyPosition.rowIndex,
        emptyPosition.colIndex
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Board;
```

Here is the tile file:

```
//Tile.ts
class Tile {
  id: number;

  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

export default Tile;
```

Here is the game css file:

```
.slider-puzzle {
  display: grid;
  background-color: gray;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    3,
    150px
  ); /* Adjust the number of columns based on your puzzle size */
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tile {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out; /* Add a transition for smooth sliding */
}

.slide-up {
  transform: translateY(-160px);
}

.slide-down {
  transform: translateY(160px);
}

.slide-left {
  transform: translateX(-160px);
}

.slide-right {
  transform: translateX(160px);
}
```

Everything seems to be working correctly except for when the slide left transition happens.  When sliding a tile left, it shows it sliding left into the right position, but after the board is updated, the tile that just slid left, appears an entire column to the left and slides to the right into its final correct position.  It only happens when sliding left and it is stumping me why it doesn't happen for all directions.

Any insight is appreciated, thank you.